# sections of tensor product bundle ( tensor product of two vector bundles )

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, tag-removed

Suppose we have a smooth manifold M and E--->M is a vector bundle. A connection on E is a linear map from the set of all smooth section on E into the set of smooth sections of the tensor product of E and the cotangent bundle of M , satisfying a condition.
Here is the question : 
We can make the tensor product bundle of two vector bundles on a same base space which is here  the smooth manifold , M , . But how can we define a  section on this new vector bundle?

Comment: First, how is your actual question related to connections? Secondly, on any bundle, you can construct a section by patching it together locally with partitions of unity!

Comment: I am not sure whether you want to define a connection on the tensor product, or prove the existence of a smooth section of the tensor product, or construct a smooth section out of smooth sections of the factor bundles of the tensor product, or define what the expression ``smooth section'' means for the tensor product bundle (given that you know what it means for the two factor bundles, I suppose).

Comment: I just want to know how we can define a sections of a tensor product of two vector bundles .


Comment: I can't tell whether you're asking for the definition of a section or for a method of constructing sections.  

Comment: the method we construct the sections of the tensor product of two vector bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $s$ is a smooth section of a vector bundle $V$ and $t$ is a smooth section of a vector bundle $W$ then $s \otimes t$ is a smooth section of $V \otimes W$. Its value at each point $m \in M$ in the underlying manifold $M$ is $(s \otimes t)(m)=s(m) \otimes t(m)$. I am still not sure if that is what you are looking for. This has nothing to do with connections, so I don't see why you mention connections in your question. If $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_p$ is a basis of local smooth sections of $V$ over an open set $U$ (i.e. these sections are defined on $U \subset M$ and every local smooth section defined on $U$ is a unique linear combination $\sum_i f_i s_i$ with $f_i$ smooth functions) and similarly $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_q$ is a basis of local sections of $W$ over the same open set $U$, then $s_i \otimes t_j$ for $i=1,2,\dots,p$ and $j=1,2,\dots,q$ is a basis of local smooth sections of $V \otimes W$ over $U$. So that should explain what all of the sections look like, I hope.